# LAMP monitoring by zabbix

Tags: monitoring, lamp, zabbix, metrics

Someone have experience with lamp monitoring ? I mean standard monitoring and slow queries monitoring for mysql, virtual hosts load as well. And alerting if something going not well.

Cacti is very cool tool for this, but it has no alerts system and it very huge. I like zabbix, its performance. But I can't find any note or plugin for apache monitoring, some tool which will take */server-status collect this data, collect data for each vhost and save this to zabbix database with graphics drawing further opportunitys =)

Also something from proc stat for mysql, collect data for each user, him stats, slow queries and so on, with graphics as result =)

Must been this tools is anywhere, I'm just can't find it...

Answer (score 2):

here are some zabbix templates to get started - http://www.zabbix.com/wiki/doku.php?id=contrib:templates

also it is not very difficult to write your own script and include results into zabbix - give it a try!

m

Answer (score 1):

1. apache - there's a quite nice howto in apache monitoring at http://www.zabbix.com/wiki/templates/apache - graph is just shiny.
2. mysql - probably more than you need at http://www.zabbix.com/wiki/howto/monitor/db/mysql/extensive_mysql_monitoring_including_replication

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have monitoring and metrics confused.  Cacti is a tool for tracking metrics (CPU or memory use over time, hits per second on Apache, etc.).  Use Cacti to spot trends and know when you need to upgrade or add systems, or to implement load balancing.

For true service monitoring and alerting, you'll want a tool like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Zabbix, but if you 're not already committed to a tool, [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) has all the monitoring plugins you're looking for as well as RRD generated performance graphs. The graphs aren't quite as nice as Cacti's but they're easy to set up. The monitoring and alerting tools are very nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix provides very few scripts out of the box, check out the documentation on "[16.2.2.MySQL](http://www.zabbix.com/downloads/ZABBIX%20Manual%20v1.4.pdf)" for a few examples.

As for apache I'm afraid you'll have to come up with your own scripts to get it right. Personally I'd reconsider Zabbix (we are dropping it right now after some evaluation) and use a combination of munin (or cacti) and [icinga](http://www.icinga.org) (well [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org) since icinga isn't quite ready yet) with IDOUtils (NDOUtils in Nagios)